# A person step out from a slowly running bus falls forward.why?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames

How does this happen? Why our body is falling forward?

Comment: Can you please elaborate more. In what direction is the bus moving, and where is the person stepping out from?

Comment: Because they were looking at their phone? *::rimshot::* I'll be here all week.

Comment: Define "forward."

Comment: I like Sheridan's answer.  In even simpler terms... When you are stepping off your body is moving (in the same direction as the bus).  Your feet stop when they make contact with the ground.  Now your body is still moving but your feet are not.  That's pretty much the definition of "falling".

Comment: Please try to make sure that your question clearly outlines the physical topic for which you wish to gain intuition. Questions that are vague such as this one and that ask simply for a quick explanation of a specific scenario are unlikely to gather answers that benefit people searching in the future.

Answer (score 2):

If a person of mass $m$ is on a bus while it is moving at a speed $v$, then they have linear momentum in the direction the bus is moving with magnitude $p=mv$. Thus, when the person steps off the bus, conservation of linear momentum says that the person will keep moving at a speed $v$ until a force is applied to the person. In this case, frictional force is applied between the person's feet and the ground which slows the person to a stop. However, before this happens, the person will have fallen in the direction that the bus was moving, likely "forward", as you have observed.

Comment: Your answer bringing to the forefront that conservation of momentum is the basis of the behavior is good. "Forward" is not really the direction they will fall, because that is a poorly defined direction. Is it the same direction as the bus's momentum? Is it the direction the person is facing? Most people step out of a bus perpendicular to the axis of the bus, so they would not fall in the direction they are facing.

Answer (score 0):

I think  in school  classes we explain the 'event'  as  happening due to the **Inertia of  motion.**

The person was sitting on the moving  bus and slowly  he comes to the door, balancing  himself.

without  asking the bus  driver to stop he steps  out of the moving  bus....

at  this instant  his body is  moving with a speed v (which is speed of the bus)...

if he is careful ,has  *habit of alighting from a moving bus* , he will  try to run along the bus on the road and slowly  decrease his speed from v to zero.

In the above manner **he will avoid the fall in the direction of moving bus**

Otherwise what is happening that **his feet  touching the ground  becomes** ***'static'*** and **the torso is still  maintaining  the inertia of  motion**

and *moves forward* , which any  bystander will  see as **a fall** in the *forward/bus movement*  direction.